# Process work in parallel with non-threadsafe function in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a lot of work (thousands of jobs) for a Scala application to process.  Each piece of work is the file name of a 100 MB file.  To process each file, I need to use an extractor object that is not thread safe (I can have multiple copies, but copies are expensive, and I should not make one per job).  What is the best way to complete this work in parallel in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your extractor in an Actor and send each file name to the actor as a message.  Since an instance of an actor will process only one message at a time, thread safety won't be an issue.  If you want to use multiple extractors, just start multiple instances of the actor and balance between them (you could write another actor to act as a load balancer).

The extractor actor(s) can then send extracted files to other actors to do the rest of the processing in parallel.

Comment: I was confused by http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242 about how to handle the number of threads when using Actors.  Since I don't have any blocking message passing, my understanding is that I can't use the Actor's thread pool.  So I should create multiple actor instances, partition the work, and sent it out among them?

Comment: Would I create a single actor that blocks and fire all my work at it?  Will the number of threads created max out at a preset size?  Or should I have multiple (one per core) event-based actors, and fire my work at them?

Comment: If you have only one actor, the application will basically be single-threaded.  Having one per core is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make 1000 jobs, but make 4x250 jobs (targeting 4 threads) and give one extractor to each batch. Inside each batch, work sequentially. This might not be optimal parallel-wise, since one batch might finish earlier but it is very easy to implement.

Probably the correct (but more complicated) solution would be to make a pool of extractors, where jobs take extractors from and put them back after finishing.

Comment: This is fairly easy with SynchromizedQueue (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedQueue.html).

Comment: It depends on the problem whether to use the sophisticated or the quick solution.

Comment: I also discovered that in Scala you can easily create the threads that use the SynchronizedQueue by using parallel collections (mycollection.par.foreach) to do the parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a thread pool, where each thread has an instance of the extractor class, and instantiate just as many of these threads as it takes to saturate the system (based on CPU usage, IO bandwidth, memory bandwidth, network bandwidth, contention for other shared resources, etc.). Then use a thread-safe work queue that these threads can pull tasks from, process them, and iterate until the container is empty.

Mind you, there should be one or several libraries in just about any modern language that implements exactly this. In C++, it would be Intel's Threading Building Blocks. In Objective-C, it would be Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: For the most simple usage of concurrency in Scala, there already exists a thread-pool. It would be nice to create one extractor for each thread of this thread-pool. Maybe using a static method...

Comment: I mean the worker threads that get used by the parallel collections in 2.9.0. Have a look at the classes in scala.collection.parallel; but I have no idea where the actually used thread pool comes from. What I meant with first comment: Maybe you can just create a pool/factory that gives out extractors based on the requesting thread and then simply use the parallel collections. They supply the threads and you supply one extractor per thread.

Answer (score 0):

It depends: what's the relative amount of CPU consumed by the extractor for each job ?

1. If it is very small, you have a classic single-producer/multiple-consumer problem for which you can find lots of solution in different languages. For Scala, if you are reluctant to start using actors, you can still use the Java API (Runnable, Executors and BlockingQueue, are quite good).
2. If it is a substantial amount (more than 10%), you app will never scale with a multithread model (see Amdhal law). You may prefer to run several process (several JVM) to obtain thread safety, and thus eliminate the non-sequential part.

Comment: This does not make sense to me and does not seem to be what Amdahl's law states.  The law says you can't speed up a program with parallelization beyond the time required to run an unparallelizable part of the code.

Comment: Amdahl Law says the speed-up you obtain is limited by the proportion of sequential time. If your extractor is not thread-safe, then it is sequential code. If it takes 20% of each job, then 20% of your code execution time will be sequential. That is to say, with an infinity of processors, you will just get a speed-up of 5x ! With a quad-core, you will only get a speed-up of 2.5x at best...

Comment: The object is not thread-safe, that's why multiple instances need to be created.  The parallelization is all about speeding up the extraction.  Look at Novelocrat's answer, for example.

Comment: Also, a thread-safe class is also sequential code, it's just written in a way that it can be used from multiple threads safetly.

Comment: I thought you said in your question that you cannot have one extractor per job. Thus, even if you manage to have several copies, the degree of parallelism will still be low and will hinder the speed-up a lot. Thread-safe code is not parallel per se, you're right, but can be trivially run in parallel. Having several process is an interesting and cheap way to isolate non-thread safe code (provided you have enough memory).

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong words.  I have thousands of files I need to process, and the extractor object is too expensive to instantiate for each file (this would create thousands of extractor instances).  However, creating one per core (a dozen or so) is fine.

Comment: I understand now (sorry I'm slow). If you can have one copy per core, then you're OK. So the point 1 in my answer applies. If you are afraid of actors, why not using the Java solution is Scala ?

Answer (score 0):

First question:  how quick does the work need to be completed?

Second question: would this work be isolated to a single physical box or what are your upper bounds on computational resource.

Third question:  does the work that needs doing to each individual "job" require blocking and is it serialised or could be partitioned into parallel packets of work?

Maybe think about a distributed model whereby you scale through designing with a mind to pushing out across multiple nodes from the first instance, actors, remoteref all that crap first...try and keep your logic simple and easy - so serialised.  Don't just think in terms of a single box.

Most answers here seem to dwell on the intricacies of spawning thread pools and executors and all that stuff - which is fine, but be sure you have a handle on the real problem first, before you start complicating your life with lots of thinking around how you manage the synchronisation logic.

If a problem can be decomposed, then decompose it.  Don't overcomplicate it for the sake of doing so - it leads to better engineered code and less sleepless nights.